# Changing scope of promise returned in a conditional import to a different variable in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise

So I have a file named hi.js which has content like this

```
export var printHi = [{
        "name":"Anki",
        "hobby":"cycling"
    },
    {
        "name":"Pinki",
        "hobby":"Swimming"
    }
];
```

My main code is like this

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And my app.js looks something like this

```
function App() {
  let dat = [];
  let name = "anki";
  if(name==="anki"){
    import('./hi.js').then(function(data){
    dat = data.printHi;
     console.log(dat); // Output returned
    })
    console.log(dat); // Empty array
  }
 console.log(dat); // Empty array and here I want the data in this variable 
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <h1>HI</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

As mentioned in the comment I am only getting the data inside .then . I am not getting data even inside if block and not inside function as well. I even tried with

```
var dat;
```

I don't know how to use the value in function because the whole function is where I have to use the value. I do not want to use DB because these values will remain static. I want some way to change the scope of the value returned by .then.
The response I am getting on console is shown below
[image: Console output]

Answer (score 0):

In React is discouraged calling function inside component body. Much better using an hook like `useEffect`. So if you want to import data from `hi.js` file one time you could write:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let dat = [];
    let name = "anki";
    if(name==="anki"){
       import('./hi.js').then(function(data){
          dat = data.printHi;
          console.log(dat); // Output returned
       })
       console.log(dat); // Here is impossible to have dat because import is async
    }
}, []);
```

Then, if you want to have `dat` value into component (to use it in `return` for example) then you have to use `useState` hook. So your code becomes:

```
function App(){
   const [dat, setDat] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {
    let name = "anki";
    if(name==="anki"){
       import('./hi.js').then(function(data){
          let result = data.printHi;
          console.log(result); // Output returned
          setDat(result);
       })
    }
   }, []);

   ...
}
```

Comment: I think my way of asking question was confusing. I am not concerned with react. That was just written to show what I was doing. My real question is that how to handle conditional import in Javascript. How to change the scope of the returned value in javascript so that I can use it inside a function and not the .then statement.